# Dough(s) to hold moist oven dish contents

Tags: oven, dough

I have a recipe at home that creates an oven dish with fairly moist contents (curry sauce, creme fraiche, cherries from a can). This specific recipe calls for ready-to-use croissant dough, which I use, and the recipe works fine.

At one point, I made this recipe with plain old puff pastry, and it turned into a soggy mess. Thus, I concluded that pre-made croissant dough is suitable for wettish oven dishes, and I've been able to use it as such. However, it has a slightly sweet innate flavor, which isn't always appropriate.

Thus: what other dough(s) can be used to create oven dishes with fairly moist contents?

Comment: I've seen recipes using phyllo, but that seems odd - it has even less oil than puff pastry, and presumably it's all that butter/oil in the croissant dough that's keeping you safe?

Comment: Did you par-bake your puff pastry?

Comment: I realized -- you never said it specifically, but I'm going to assume that this was for a top crust, and not a bottom crust, based on the type of bread-like-product you mentioned.

Comment: @justkt - no, no par-baking. @Joe - crust all around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done pot pies with both puff pastry, and with the refrigerated croissant dough.  A few things I've noticed:

- It will not work from a frozen state.  You need to thaw the puff pastry for it to work.  (my assumption is that it doesn't get the fast heat it needs to puff, as you've got a heat sink right below it with so much moisture)
- It will not work as a complete sheet.  You want to cut it into smaller squares or triangles, so there's a gap for steam to escape, or at the very least, vent it like you would a pie.

I've also done 'drop biscuit' dough in similar dishes ... you might also want to look at dumpling recipies, to see how they compare.

Answer (score 5):

Canned biscuit dough might be a good neutral substitute (you'd have to roll/cut/tear it as appropriate), or just make your own equivalent (flour + butter + milk = tasty).

Answer (score 4):

You might also be able to seal your puff pastry with a good layer of oil or clarified butter befor adding the filling.

Answer (score 2):

Pizza or bread dough.

Maybe you'll have to bake it a few minutes before adding the moist contents, but bread can be used as a bowl for soups...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a site for suet pastry that can be used for sweet or savory dishes. I hope this helps,all the best.

http://www.greenchronicle.com/basics/suet_crust_pastry.htm